# Uncaught TypeError: is not a function in RazorPay callback

Tags: angular, typescript, razorpay

I have a handler defined like this in my typescript class

```
  "handler": function (response) {
              this.sendUserStatus();
  },
```

But when i call  **this.sendUserStatus();** i am getting following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.sendUserStatus is not a function
```

How do i make this call  this.sendUserStatus()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an arrow function:

```
"handler": (response) => this.sendUserStatus()
```

Otherwise the `this` context is lost if you use the `function` keyword.

Also, be aware that you are using angular, and these kind of events are probably not patched by ngZone. You should re-enter the zone:

```
constructor(private ng: NgZone) {}

"handler": this.ng.run(() => (response) => this.sendUserStatus())
```

Comment: And Kruijit any idea why i am getting this "serviceworker" must be a dictionary in your web app manifest. in my console

Comment: @NidhinPaul try clearing the site data in the dev tools/application tab. Or use an incognito window